# leetCode590. N-ary Tree Postorder Traversal

Tags: algorithm, graph, stack, depth-first-search, graph-traversal

I am trying to solve LeetCode problem [590. N-ary Tree Postorder](https://leetcode.com/problems/n-ary-tree-postorder-traversal/description/):

> Given the root of an n-ary tree, return the postorder traversal of its nodes' values.

I made code considering each condition.

I solved some test cases, but I got an error in testcase 28 which is so big that I can't even debug and follow it.

So I need your help.

1. What is wrong in my code?
2. Do you have some advice for coding style and way of practice?

Below is my code:

```cpp
/*
// Definition for a Node.
class Node {
public:
    int val;
    vector<Node*> children;       // 벡터노드가 자식 노드들을 배열로 가지고 있다.

    Node() {}

    Node(int _val) {
        val = _val;
    }

    Node(int _val, vector<Node*> _children) {
        val = _val;
        children = _children;
    }
};
*/

class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> postorder(Node* root) {
        // 이진트리가 아니다 
        // 후순위 탐색이다. 
        // 자식부터 탐색한다는 점에서 우선 dfs인듯하다 -> stack 활용 

        vector<Node*> stack;
        Node* current = root;
        vector<int> ans;

        if(!current){
            return ans;
        }


        stack.push_back(current);           // stack에 넣기

        while(!stack.empty()) {

            current = stack.back();

            if(!(current->children).empty()){           // 자식이 있는 경우
                int n = (current->children).size();
                for(int i = n-1; i>=0;i--){
                    stack.push_back((current->children)[i]);
                }
            }

            else{
                ans.push_back(current->val);           // 자식이 없는 경우 
                int temp = (stack.back())->val;
                stack.pop_back();
                bool chk = false;            

                if(!stack.empty()){

                    current = stack.back(); // 3이 걸림
                    vector<Node*> v = current->children;
                    int m = v.size();

                    for(int i = 0; i < m; i++){  // 이걸 반복해야할텐데 
                        if((v[i]->val) == temp){  
                            chk = true;
                        } 
                    }

                    while(chk&&!stack.empty()) {                     // 쭉 딸려 올라가도록 

                        ans.push_back(current->val);     
                        int temp = (stack.back())->val;
                        stack.pop_back();
                        chk = false;
                        
                        if(!stack.empty()){
                            current = stack.back(); // 3이 걸림
                            vector<Node*> v = current->children;
                            int m = v.size();

                            for(int i = 0; i < m; i++){ // 이걸 반복해야할텐데 
                                if((v[i] ->val) == temp){  
                                    chk = true;
                                } 
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    // 3에서 탈출 
                }
            }


        }

        return ans;
    }

};
```

The challenging issue I had was when removing nodes from the stack, when to do it.

So I made a while loop using the boolean `chk`.

And now I can't even guess what is the problem:

1. What is my mistake?
2. Any advice for my coding style and way of practice?

Comment: What is this code supposed to do? Please include a description in the question. Users on this site should not need to visit external sites to find out what your question is about. On a related note, code is read by people from around the world, so comments are much more useful when they are in English.

Comment: Input is root node and we need to post-order-travel and return it as vector. Thanks for your advice :)

Comment: So what does this do? `if((v[i]->val) == temp){ chk = true; }` Postorder traversal doesn't need to look at values.

Comment: I got problem on test-case 28 and that is so big testcase. So I coulden't debug it one by one and find what's the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So I made while loop using boolean chk.

The idea is not bad, but you are comparing with `temp`, which is not reliable, as there is no guarantee that the nodes will have all distinct values. You should compare the node *pointer* instead.

Secondly, you don't need a loop. The only time you should potentially have a match, is with the *last* child of a parent node, since that child was pushed on the stack right after its parent.

I didn't verify the deeply nested code, as it should not be necessary to have so much repetition of code. This is the common advice given: [Don't repeat yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Here is how you could fix your code:

```cpp
class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> postorder(Node* root) {
        vector<Node*> stack;
        Node* current = root;
        Node* last = nullptr;
        vector<int> ans;
        
        if (!current){
            return ans;
        }
        stack.push_back(current);
        while (!stack.empty()) {
            current = stack.back();
            int n = (current->children).size();
            for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                stack.push_back((current->children)[i]);
            }
            while (stack.size() > 0) {
                current = stack.back();
                if ((current->children).size() > 0 && current->children.back() != last) {
                    break; // current node needs to be expanded
                }
                // All children of current node were visited. 
                //    Output the node's value, and remove it from the stack
                last = current; // Keep track of last processed node
                ans.push_back(last->val);
                stack.pop_back();
            }
            // If at this point the stack is not empty, then its top has a 
            //  node that still needs to be expanded,
            //   ... which will happen in the next iteration of the loop
        }
        return ans;
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks. Through this exampe, now I understand more about the difference between inorder-traversal and postorder-traversal.